# Shrinking Sticky Navigation Bar

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have the following code on my site for my nav bar: http://jsfiddle.net/faj0o4cq/

It works great without any of the `margin-top` parts, but when I add them in it breaks. See how this works fine: http://jsfiddle.net/faj0o4cq/1/

What am I doing wrong in my Javascript?

```js
$(function(){
        $('#header_nav').data('size','big');
    });

    $(window).scroll(function(){
        if($(document).scrollTop() > 0)
        {
            if($('#header_nav').data('size') == 'big')
            {
                $('#header_nav').data('size','small');
                $('#header_nav').stop().animate({
                    height:'78px'
                },600);
                $('header nav').stop().animate({
                    margin-top:'50px'
                },600);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            if($('#header_nav').data('size') == 'small')
            {
                $('#header_nav').data('size','big');
                $('#header_nav').stop().animate({
                    height:'100px'
                },600);
                $('header nav').stop().animate({
                    margin-top:'100px'
                },600);
            }  
        }
    });
```

```css
#header_nav {
    background:blue;
    height:100px;
    position:fixed;
    top:0
}

body {
    height:9000px
}
```

```html
<header>
<div id="header_nav">
    <nav>nav here</nav>
</div>
</header>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to enclose `margin-top` in quotation marks.

Every time, if something related to JavaScript does not work, check the console. It may give you some hints on what is wrong.

```js
$(function(){
        $('#header_nav').data('size','big');
    });

    $(window).scroll(function(){
        if($(document).scrollTop() > 0)
        {
            if($('#header_nav').data('size') == 'big')
            {
                $('#header_nav').data('size','small');
                $('#header_nav').stop().animate({
                    height:'78px'
                },600);
                $('header nav').stop().animate({
                    'margin-top':'50px'
                },600);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            if($('#header_nav').data('size') == 'small')
            {
                $('#header_nav').data('size','big');
                $('#header_nav').stop().animate({
                    height:'100px'
                },600);
                $('header nav').stop().animate({
                    'margin-top':'100px'
                },600);
            }  
        }
    });
```

```css
#header_nav {
    background:blue;
    height:100px;
    position:fixed;
    top:0
}

body {
    height:9000px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<header>
<div id="header_nav">
    <nav>nav here</nav>
</div>
</header>
```

Comment: Oh dear. That looks very obvious now you point it out. I'll remember that in the future. Thank you so so much for taking the time to help. Lesson learned :-)